# Python / Pandas: Dataframe multiple filters

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

I have the following dataframe which is list of races and results.

```
      Date       R   H   Fin  Win
0     11182017   1   1   2     0 
1     11182017   1   2   1     5   
2     11182017   1   3   3     0   
3     11182017   2   1   2     0   
4     11182017   2   2   1     10   
5     11182017   3   1   1     6    
6     11182017   3   2   2     0
```

I want to be able to filter first by race (R) then by horse (H) and return the results.

For the dataset above when R = 1 I want to see only H 1 & 2 (ie filter out H 3 for R 1). For R  = 2 I want to to see only H 1 (ie filter out H 2 for R 2) and for R =3 I only want to see H 2 (ie filter out H 1 for R 3). I would accomplish this by setting a variable preferably via a prompt. Essentially I am trying to "scratch" certain horses from a particular race

Results Example below

```
      Date       R   H   Fin  Win
0     11182017   1   1   2     0 
1     11182017   1   2   1     5    
3     11182017   2   1   2     0   
6     11182017   3   2   2     0
```

Comment: I assume `R` is race. But what is Horse? Couldn't see the why # 1 and 2 would be returned for `R=1` and #1 for `R=2`

Comment: Updated my question and clarified a bit, hope that helps! Thanks

Comment: Well I am looking to be dynamic, ie the change the variable set or prompt result and filter on the criteria. But yes I know but also want to change it.

Comment: So you want the user to input a value for `R` and for `H` and you'd return the new data frame?

Comment: Essentially yes for a set of races, I want to be able to remove Horses BY Race. So i want to be able to say for Race 1 remove horse 3. So first question is what race are you interested and and the for that race what do you want to remove. Don't need to do this by prompt per say but by variables that could be edited before executed the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dictionary is an option for storing races and horse in that you would not need to create unnecessary variables every time you run a new filtering setup, here I use a dictionary with keys = races and values = list of horses

```
d = {1:[1,2],2:[1]}
```

Now you can use the [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) function, which accepts a query string. This can be made by iterating over the dictionary

```
query_str = ' | '.join(['((R == {x}) and (H in {y}))'.format(x=x,y=y) for x,y in d.items()])
```

The string generated with list comp would look like this in this example

```
((R == 1) and (H in [1, 2])) | ((R == 2) and (H in [1]))
```

Now you can run

```
df.query(query_str)
```

and get

```
       Date  Fin  H  R  Win
0  11182017    2  1  1    0
1  11182017    1  2  1    5
3  11182017    2  1  2    0
```

---

Additional Notes on User input to create dictionary

**Code**

```
d = {}
x = input('Add races ')
for i in x:
    d[i] = list(input('Add Horses for Race: {} '.format(i)))
print d
```

**Sample Run**

```
Add races 1,2,3
Add Horses for Race: 1 1,2
Add Horses for Race: 2 2,3
Add Horses for Race: 3 3,4
{1: [1, 2], 2: [2, 3], 3: [3, 4]}
```

Comment: I do like this option, thank you for this. This may be a different question but is there a way to build the dictionary via the user prompts as in the answer by @RafaelC below?

Comment: Sure, I added the info to the question. I did not cover it because you had stated in the comments that you did not need that. If this is something you are just running yourself I would avoid user inputs, to avoid writing code for exception handling. Also I felt that @RafaelC covered inputs sufficiently in his answer

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you want someone to input `R` and `H` to get values... You can use `input` in `python3`.

```
races = input("Enter races: ").split(",")
ind = []
for race in races:
    sub = df[df["R"] == int(race)]
    horses = input("Enter horses to show for race {0}: ".format(race)).split(",")
    rows = sub.H.isin(horses)
    ind.extend(rows[rows].index.values)

print(df[df.index.isin(ind)])
```

---

Example:

```
Enter races: 1,2
Enter horses for race 1: 1,2
Enter horses for race 2: 2
   R  H
0  1  1
1  1  2
4  2  2
```